# WSO2 Authentication Failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I logged in as admin in the carbon/admin of the api management but I keep seeing this error when I access the statistics tab.

Authentication failed:Error processing data: java.io.IOException: Error looking up user javax.security.auth.login.AccountNotFoundException: Invalid User : guest {org.wso2.andes.server.handler.ConnectionStartOkMethodHandler}

Comment: API Manager doesn't have a user called `guest` by default. Please check your configuration changes and customizations if there are any.

Comment: I never remembered adding any user when I was configuring DAS and APIM. The only user I know is admin.

Comment: Please post the entire error trace.